# Will installing Ubuntu erase OS on chosen disk?

Tags: system-installation, disk

If using "Something Else" option during instalation of Ubuntu for boot loader installation I choose a device that already has one OS (ubuntu 6.06 in that case) will this OS be removed or will new ubuntu install alongside it? Do I have to format the partition?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do and what you actually do. If you make a mistake in **Something else** it will erase the partition with the OS.

Comment: To save your existing OS, you want to dual-boot. Here's the Ubuntu instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Something else" is a manual configuration, so there are too many possibilities to give an accurate answer to this.

Generally speaking, installing to a partition with data on it will destroy that data.

Answer (score 0):

If it is of a format Ubuntu will install on, that OS is toast, but /home data will likely be fine. I recommend backing that up in case it all goes sideways like it did for me this last week. If you have to format the partition before installing. It's all gone.